# Example of a white noise series that is not a martingale difference series with respect to its natural filtration

Tags: stochastic-processes, examples-counterexamples, time-series

For a homework exercise, I am asked to find an example of a white noise series that is not a martingale difference series with respect to its natural filtration. Does anyone know an example? I read somewhere you could use the cosine function, but I am not sure how to deploy that.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the non-linear moving average process
$$ y_t = \epsilon_t + \epsilon_{t-1} \epsilon_{t-2},$$
where we take $\epsilon_t \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ to be i.i.d. random variables. We can easily show that this is a white noise process but 
$$\mathbb{E} [y_t | y_{t-1},y_{t-2},\ldots] = \mathbb{E} [y_t | \epsilon_{t-1},\epsilon_{t-2},\ldots] = \epsilon_{t-1} \epsilon_{t-2} \neq 0,$$
By noticing that $\sigma(y_t,y_{t-1},\ldots)=\sigma(\epsilon_t,\epsilon_{t-1},\ldots)$. Hence $y_t$ is not a martingale difference series.

Comment: I tried to copy your proof, but I got stuck when I wanted to prove that $$\sigma(y_t,y_{t-1},\ldots) = \sigma(\varepsilon_{t},\varepsilon_{t-1},\ldots).$$ The inclusion $\subset$ is obvious, but how did you show the other inclusion?

Comment: @Ghostface Did you manage to prove the reverse inclusion in the meantime?